Flutter convenient/integration test stay on screen test starting
When running the test starting with convenient test and integration test, i cannot find widgets because it don't launch the application and stay on place holder flutter of integration test which is a simple screen with "Test starting".
The logs:
debugDumpApp
I/flutter (11799): MyIntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding - DEBUG MODE
I/flutter (11799): [root]
I/flutter (11799): └View
I/flutter (11799):  └_RawView-[_DeprecatedRawViewKey TestFlutterView#18da9](renderObject: _ReusableRenderView#4156f)
I/flutter (11799):   └_ViewScope
I/flutter (11799):    └_PipelineOwnerScope
I/flutter (11799):     └_MediaQueryFromView(state: _MediaQueryFromViewState#0aa40)
I/flutter (11799):      └MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 890.3), devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaler: no scaling, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 50.3, 0.0, 0.0), viewPadding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 50.3, 0.0, 0.0), viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, systemGestureInsets: EdgeInsets(29.7, 62.5, 29.7, 8.0), alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, onOffSwitchLabels: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional, gestureSettings: DeviceGestureSettings(touchSlop: 8.0), displayFeatures: [DisplayFeature(rect: Rect.fromLTRB(182.5, 0.0, 229.0, 50.3), type: DisplayFeatureType.cutout, state: DisplayFeatureState.unknown)]))
I/flutter (11799):       └RepaintBoundary(renderObject: RenderRepaintBoundary#8a7da)
I/flutter (11799):        └Container-[#dd3fa]
I/flutter (11799):         └Center(alignment: Alignment.center, renderObject: RenderPositionedBox#ec64f)
I/flutter (11799):          └Text("Test starting...", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff917fff), size: 40.0, textDirection: ltr, dependencies: [MediaQuery])
I/flutter (11799):           └RichText(textDirection: ltr, softWrap: wrapping at box width, maxLines: unlimited, text: "Test starting...", renderObject: RenderParagraph#c907d relayoutBoundary=up1)
I/flutter (11799):
I/flutter (11799):
I/flutter (11799): !debugDumpApp

So cannot find button "loginButton: Found 0 widgets with key [<'GoToLoginButton'>]: []".

I tried to pump and settle with ConvenientTest and Flutter tester nativ:
Here is the code:
void main() {
  EditableText.debugDeterministicCursor = true;

  convenientTestMain(MySlot(), () {
    group('Tests', () {
      tTestWidgets('Maintenance plan', (t) async {
        try {
          print('pump and settle');
          await t.pumpAndSettle(); // don't work
          // await t.tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 3)); don't work too
        } catch (e) {
          print('pump and settle error: $e');
        }

        print('debugDumpApp');
        debugDumpApp();
        print('!debugDumpApp');

        final loginButton = find.byKey(const ValueKey('GoToLoginButton'));

        print('loginButton: $loginButton');
      });
    });
  });
}

class MySlot extends ConvenientTestSlot {
  @override
  Future<void> appMain(AppMainExecuteMode mode) async => app.mainApp(flavor: 'dev');

  @override
  BuildContext? getNavContext(ConvenientTest t) => navigatorKey.currentContext;
}

The main is not async but before running app i run api calls with await in function "launchAndRunApp":
static void launchAndRunApp(String flavor, Widget app) async {
    /// Encapsulate app with Sentry to track errors
    await SentryFlutter.init(
      (options) {
        // my options
      },
      appRunner: () async {
        await launchBeforeAppRun();

        return runApp(app);
      },
    );
  }

I think it could be this.
